# Best pattern for labels on website based on client profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns, configuration

I have a requirement to make our current web application configurable based on client profile. So basically, allowing the application to scale and customize itself based on who the customer is. My current requirement to start off with will be simple, which is to make text within the web application configurable. So ATM, there will be 2 possible profiles, and based on which profile you select (either through AppSetting or database), all labels need to render accordingly. I can think of many ways of doing this. One thing I don't want to do is storing the label values in a database table because ATM there is no requirement to modify the labels through an interface, so I was thinking perhaps Resource files?

Also, my next requirement will be to all features within the website to be turned on/off based on profile, so I Need to keep this into consideration. Sometimes a feature will share 90% of the logic, so it wouldnt be feasible to duplicate to the feature and make the 10% changes for that profile and then have 2 copies of the same feature with minimum differences. So I'm looking for a solution for this as well. Perhaps an overall design that would cover both requirements?

Any advice will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by ATM(Automatic Teller Machine)?

Comment: @abdul-rahman-k ATM - At the moment.

Comment: Should this question be migrated to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Making the text within the web application configurable sounds like something that the end users would like to change. So I'm not sure how you plan to avoid this in the future.

Comment: @lloyd this question is rather poor fit for Programmers - it could be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score -1):

According to my understanding you need to update labels in the website and provide some features based on the profile selected.

So to do this , I would like to do this:

First implement MVC pattern, where our website will be in View , Model will be the Profile class and controller will host all the business logic.

If we don't want to use Database, we can serialize the object of Profile class and store (for [ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/store.html)
), in that we can have a File object which is a config file, where we can store the names of the features available to that profile.

At run time read all the features available for that profile and hence populate the view(website). This can be done by using either Inversion of Control Pattern.  Like this:

```
public interface IFeatures{...}

public class Feature1 implements IFeatures{...}

public class Feature2 implements IFeatures{...}

public class Profile{
  private String name;
  private String pwd;
  private File configFile;
  ...
}

public class Controller{

    public List<?> getFeauturesForProfile(Profile p){

      List<IFeatures> features;
      List<String>feautures = scanConfigFileForFeatures(p.getConfigFile()); 
      for(String feature : features)
         features = Class.forName(feature).newInstance();
      return features

    }

}
```

Since I'm familiar with only java , I have written the syntax-es in java .